# Finite projection in Von Neumann algebra

Tags: von-neumann-algebras

I had the following question when I am learning von Neumann algebras: 
Let p be a finite projection in a finite von Neumann algebra $M$, let $p>p_1>p_2>\cdots$ be a decreasing sequence of projections such that $p_i\neq p_{i+1}$. Is such a sequence necessarily of finite length? 
Any help or recommendations on books/papers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Any help or recommendations on books/papers are greatly appreciated" - which book are you learning from? Surely any half-decent book would either tell you the answer to this, or have it as one of the exercises?

Comment: Indeed, type II-1 von Neumann algebras have no minimal non-zero idempotents. So the answer to your question is not just negative, it is negative "most of the time".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is **no**.  Abelian von Neumann algebras are finite, but it is easy to find examples of such algebras with infinite decreasing sequences of projections.  For instance, one may take $M = L^\infty(\mathbb{R},\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, and let $p_i \in M$ be the element corresponding to the characteristic function of $[0,\frac{1}{i}]$.

**Update:** Now that you've seen some counterexamples, this might be a good follow-up "homework" problem for you (depending on how much you know about [measure theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharam%27s_theorem) and [abelian von Neumann algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_von_Neumann_algebra#Classification)): prove that a (finite) von Neumann algebra $M$ satisfies your descending chain condition on projections if and only if it is a finite dimensional algebra.

(Hint: think about a type decomposition.)

Answer (score 6):

I do not think that this true. Take for example the sequence of matrix algebras with $A_0 = \mathbb{C}$ and $A_n = M_2(\mathbb{C}) \otimes A_{n-1}$ equipped with their normalized traces and the diagonal embeddings $A_{n} \to A_{n+1}$. The direct limit $A$ of this sequence is a $*$-algebra with a trace and the GNS-construction with respect to this trace state yields a (faithful) representation $H$, on which $A$ acts. The weak closure $M$ of $A$ is a von Neumann algebra, which is of type $II_1$ (in particular, it is finite). This is known as the hyperfinite type $II_1$-factor.

Now consider the sequence of projections starting with $p_0 = 1 \in A_0$, 
$$
p_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \in A_1 = M_2(\mathbb{C})
$$

$$
p_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \in A_2 \cong M_2(\mathbb{C}) \otimes M_2(\mathbb{C})
$$

etc. (I hope the pattern is clear). We have $tr(p_n) = 2^{-n}$. Therefore $p_i \neq p_j$ if $i \neq j$. But $p_0 > p_1 > p_2 > \dots$

In fact, constructions like this are the reason for many of the cool features of type $II$ von Neumann algebras.

Comment: Any Type II_1 contains no minimal non-zero projections

Comment: @Yemon: That is true. I just tried to give the most concrete example of such a sequence, I could think of.